# XPS 9560 shutting down after log in to ubuntu

Tags: login, shutdown

Freshed install Ubuntu on my machine (no dual boot).

I start my computer and when I login to Ubuntu, the computer shuts down (in full charged + plugged), without notice.

Did anyone had a similar issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: The 95X0 series of XPS laptops have had thermal issues reported in the past, when you boot to the system can you get into the BIOS and view its logs of the shutdown events to see if there was any thermal triggers for the shutdown events?

Comment: So in thermal events, I have no events. In the power events, the shutdown appear with the message "ACPI power management".

Comment: Tried to install Fedora and it gives me an error that might help:

Comment: /oldsys/[sys/proc/run/dev] : special device /oldsys/[sys/proc/run/dev] does not exist (4 lines with each case in each)